# « [...] en attendant d'être remis à un « sponsor » » : extension de sens, guillemets ?

Tags: sens, anglais, synonymes, emprunts, guillemets

Dans une section (« Parrain ») d'un article on peut lire que :

> Près de 15 000 mineurs non accompagnés sont actuellement détenus, en
>   attendant d'être remis à un « sponsor », souvent un membre de la
>   famille déjà installé aux États-Unis.
>
> [ [Une fillette meurt en rétention aux États-Unis, cruel rappel du
>   drame des enfants migrants](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/201812/14/01-5208104-une-fillette-meurt-en-retention-aux-etats-unis-cruel-rappel-du-drame-des-enfants-migrants.php), ds. *La Presse* via AFP, 14 décembre
>   2018 ]

Dans le domaine de la citoyenneté et de l'immigration au Canada, par exemple, on a le [*répondant* ou le *parrain*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=SPONSOR&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), avec l'idée de *se porter [garant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/garant) de quelqu'un*.

L'emprunt à l'anglais [*sponsor*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sponsor), l'équivalent de [*commanditaire*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26526901) ou de *parrain*, peut se [transposer](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=sponsor&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search), selon que ce soit une société ou une personne, pour un bénéfice direct ou non, en le *parraineur* ou le *mécène*, la personne qui *apporte un soutien* (financier, matériel etc.) etc. et déborde du domaine sportif. Dans ce sens-là (*commanditaire*) on évite le terme *parrain* (la personne qui apporte un soutien moral) nous dit-on.

- Quand on emploie *sponsor* en français, utilise-t-on généralement les
  guillemets ; dans la citation, à quoi servent les guillemets :
  s'agit-il d'un sens différents de *sponsor*, de son approximation ou
  est-ce un signe de lexicalisation incomplète (voire de dé-lexicalisation ?) ?
- Le sens de *sponsor* s'étend-il aussi à toute personne qui *apporte un soutien* quel qu'il soit ; à la personne qui *se porte garant* de quelqu'un ?
- Quel terme français se substituerait à *sponsor* dans la citation ?

Comment: Je crois que le terme français adapté est très précisément celui que vous avez évoqué : *Un soutien* (Sens 2.b du TLF) qui au passage suggère une liste de synonymes dont j'extrais au passage : *protecteur* qui ne me semble pas mal non plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J'ai rencontré ce mécanisme sous d'autres cieux et pour des raisons commerciales : dans nombre de pays, une société étrangère doit être chaperonnée par une société ou une personnalité locale pour pouvoir travailler. Cette dernière « répond » (latin *responsus*, d'où le mot sponsor) devant la loi du bon comportement de son protégé. Il se fait payer en conséquence.
J'ai toujours employé le mot **garant** pour transcrire cette obligation, ce qui doit correspondre à la terminologie juridique concernée.

Autre point : la typographie française courante utilise l'italique pour les mots étrangers non francisés (graphie étrangère, sans accent ou trait d'union pour les mots anglais et latins par exemple). Les guillemets conviennent plutôt à la mise en question (sens secondaire, argot, ironie, etc.) d'une locution ou d'un mot existant.
Dans votre exemple, je proposerais : « […] en attendant d'être remis à un garant (*sponsor*), souvent […] ».

Comment: Merci ! _...ce qui doit correspondre_ : si vous croisez le terme sur un site de l'État qui explique le régime dont vous parlez ou réfère à la loi qui le constitue, et où le terme serait employé, n'hésitez pas à confirmer, par l'ajout d'un lien par exemple.

Comment: Le mot sponsor reste le plus courant car le droit utilisé est en général anglo-saxon. Voici un exemple (Dubaï) qui détaille le concept : https://www.justlanded.com/francais/Dubai/Guide-Just-Landed/Emploi/Sponsoring

Answer (score 1):

Uniquement en ce qui a trait au troisième point, j'ai trouvé le terme « regroupant »<sup>1</sup> (la substantivation du participe présent du verbe [*regrouper*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/regrouper)) qui semble utile vu le contexte de la citation rappelant ou s'apparentant à celui du [*regroupement familial*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=REGROUPEMENT%20FAMILIAL&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)...

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Dans le texte de la *[Directive 2003/86/CE du Conseil du 22 septembre 2003 relative au droit au regroupement familial](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN-FR/TXT/?qid=1545161336126&uri=CELEX:32003L0086&from=EN)* du Conseil de l'Union européenne on a utilisé à 35 reprises ce terme en français là où on avait *sponsor* dans la version en langue anglaise. C'est présenté à titre d'illustration.</sub>

Comment: Intéressant. Ce terme, *regroupant*, me semble plus spécialisé que *sponsor*. Un sponsor peut être n'importe qui qui en accepte le rôle, mais n'est pas forcément regroupant qui veut.